# Checksum error while installing ambari

Tags: linux, centos, redhat, unix

While installing ambari server,getting following error.

> yum install ambari-server -y
>
> ```
> Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile Updates-ambari-1.7.0
> | 2.9 kB 00:00 Updates-ambari-1.7.0/primary_db
> | 3.5 kB 00:00 http://public-repo-1.hortonworks.com/ambari/centos6/1.x/updates/1.7.0/repodata/22c697ef57d567fd7954346bccd09e54cfcd830f22f15a6ceeddac109db8fe8f-primary.sqlite.bz2:
> ```
>
> [Errno -3] Error performing checksum Trying other mirror.
>
> Updates-ambari-1.7.0/primary_db
> | 3.5 kB 00:00 http://public-repo-1.hortonworks.com/ambari/centos6/1.x/updates/1.7.0/repodata/22c697ef57d567fd7954346bccd09e54cfcd830f22f15a6ceeddac109db8fe8f-primary.sqlite.bz2:
>
> [Errno -3] Error performing checksum Trying other mirror. Error:
> failure:
> repodata/22c697ef57d567fd7954346bccd09e54cfcd830f22f15a6ceeddac109db8fe8f-primary.sqlite.bz2
> from Updates-ambari-1.7.0: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.

Answer (score 0):

1. Clean the yum cache

   ```
   $ yum clean all
   ```
2. Then recreate the cache

   ```
   $ yum make cache
   ```
3. Finally, attempt to install

   ```
   $ yum install ambari-server
   ```